# Can I make a hotkey dependent on the URL that is open?

Tags: autohotkey

So my question is if there is a way that I can give a key another meaning wether `https://de.overleaf.com/` is open or not. Also regardless what comes after the "/". Or is this too much to ask for?

Comment: If your browser changes its window title based off what website you have open, this is trivial to do. Just create [context sensitive hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Context) with the [`#IfWinActive` directive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_IfWinActive.htm). For example Google Chrome changes its title to `autohotkey - Can I make a hotkey dependent on the URL that is open? - Stack Overflow - Google Chrome` on this page. If your browser can't do that, or the title it changes to isn't specific enough, you'll need a more advanced approach.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out an answer to my question. If you use the Autocontrol extension of chrome you can make a condition when a certain URL is active to change the key to another input. Under actions -> advanced actions -> synthesize input you can alter the key.